# Is it safe to install this hot water tank from ebay?

Tags: water, water-heater

Is it safe for me to replace my electric hot water tank with this [continuous electric unit that I bought on ebay](http://cgi.ebay.com.au/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=300691866075)?

(I'm in Australia)

---

[image]

```
Technical Specifications

rated power                  6.0KW
rated voltage            220V-50Hz
working pressure             0.02-0.8(MPa)
International electric wire  4m㎡
Electric meter requirements  ≥10(40)A
Waterproof grade             △IPX4
Ammeter                  30A
Leakage switch           30A
Item Size                    330mm*220mm*65mm
```

Comment: You haven't provided any info on your experience or how you plan to install it, so how can anyone here answer if what you might do would be safe? If you have to ask, the answer is probably no.

Comment: I plan to just connect the hoses as it is with the hot water tank - and the power.

Comment: for starters it will be illegal due to the non complaince in au of the unit. but apart from that its 6kw heating elemet so it could pull 26 amps... so dont just put a plug on the end of it and plug it in. just a personal opinion dont do it just spend the money and get a proper unit

Comment: I was planning on just re-routing the power from the hot water tank into the unit

Comment: My personal circumstances don't allow for me to buy a proper, larger hot water tank. I wouldn't be asking the question if I could get a beautiful 400L off-peak tank to save money. I want a "per use" hot water system because it's just me and I only use it occasionally. A tank would just be wasting money every day. I understand your concerns, and thank you for your concern, but I would like to try this if it is feasible.

Answer (score 1):

As RedGrittyBrick mentioned it may not be safe. It is not legal in Australia as it is only certified by Chinese standards and the installation of said unit is against the law ( not really a problem for you unless someone else uses it and gets electrocuted, you sell it, or sell the dwelling you are connecting it to. For reference perhaps look up "solar and bamboo faulty tanks")

One of the reasons I would be concerned about the safety is my experience with imported products "waterproofing" certification.

You will note the plastic union on the outlet of the unit which is there for a voltage break (Scary).

Also the unit specifies 4mm2 cable, I do not put on that I'm a sparky but this webpage explains [How to calculate the draw on cable](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_calculate_the_maximum_withstandable_current_in_a_cable) and considering the example is for 5Kw at ambient temperature and this unit is drawing 6Kw at high temperature in an enclosed compartment I would question the sizing ( unfortunately I do not have the cable sizing code on hand at the moment for AU).

The quality of the controller would also concern me having installed direct import controllers before and see them fail and allow constant heating of the element but you should be able to hop out of the way pretty quick if that were to happen.

In summery I would say not particularly safe but if its only you using it you probably will get away with it.

[Un- Watermarked hot water unit installation](http://www.fairtrading.nsw.gov.au/About_us/News_and_events/Media_releases/2012_media_releases/20120507_solar_system_seller_fined_and_prosecuted_by_fair_trading.html)

Comment: so you're basically questioning the safety of the actual unit, not my installation plans?
they've sold hundreds of these units on ebay with 99.7% positive feedback... so I'm happy to assume that the unit itself is safe. I'm just wondering about my installation plans.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, your installation plans should be ok just check the wire size from your existing unit and the breaker amperage

Answer (score 1):

I am an Australian and a Home Automation System Integrator and I can tell you legally you can't engage in any electrical or plumbing works without a licensce.

Also you may also void your Insurance Policy if you make a claim and the water system was the direct cause of the problem (i.e. Fire or Leakage).

Comment: The federal government states that you can't, how ever that doesnt mean you can't ;)

Comment: Trust me everything in Australia is regulated (democratically)

Answer (score 0):

It may not be safe.

My hot water tank has a 3 kW electric immersion heater. So the electric wiring to this would not be suitable for a 6 kW electric shower.

However my immersion heater is only a secondary system used if my gas-fired boiler is not working for any reason. So your water heater may be rated higher if it is the primary water heater.

You can check the circuit breaker rating and the wire cross-sectional area. I have 16 A  breakers for the immersion heater and 32 A breakers for my electric showers but I think they are 8 kW units.

---

I'm not sure what the regulations are like in Australia but you may need to get new electrical work in a bathroom shower safety checked.